# Unexpected T_STRING in PHP

Tags: php

I get an error in my PHP script. Someone please kindly help me fix it. Thank you.

```
$sql="SELECT username, description, website FROM members WHERE City="NY" order by username";
```

Comment: If you have double quotes inside a double quoted string, you need to escape them (`\"`).... or use single quotes (`'`) around your `NY`

Comment: use this $sql="SELECT username, description, website FROM members WHERE City='NY' order by username";

Comment: Thank you so mouch =.=! such a similar mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the inner quotes:

```
$sql="SELECT username, description, website FROM members WHERE City=\"NY\" order by username";
```